# R extension not formating on VScode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I've installed the VScode extensio "R" `v2.5.0` by REditorSupport. After some debugging, I had it working so I could `Alt` + `Shift` + `F` and have VScode auto-indent my R code. Then I opened RStudio, did some stuff and went back to VScode only to find receive a message saying `There is no formatted for 'r' files installed.` (image below).

What gives? I didn't uninstall anything, the extension is still there and I can't find any setting that looks like `formatting` or `indent`.

## How can I configure the R extension to keep auto-indenting my R code?

[image]

Comment: Cannot help here, but maybe the good folks over at https://superuser.com/

Comment: Have you installed the `languageserver` and `styler` R packages?